# How are characters expected to traverse area B3 of the Cellar Complex (Encounter 9) in Waterdeep: Dragon Heist?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, waterdeep-dragon-heist

In reading through and preparing to run *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* (looking at Xanathar, Spring variation) I was wondering about mechanisms/methods of gaining entrance to the [Cellar Complex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/dragon-season#Encounter9CellarComplex) (the section starting on p. 83 of the adventure).  I think I'm missing something simple.

The [Spring subsection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/dragon-season#CellarComplexSpring) (p. 85) states that

> you come down via the wig shop into B1; there is a walkway on B2, but no walkway on B3, plus the sewage is 3 ft deep.

Is the expectation that

> PCs will wade through the sewage from B2 to B4 via B3,

or is there some other expected/standard method PCs would likely take?

Comment: Welcome to the rpg stack! I am almost sure this is a D&D 5e question, can you confirm (and add the dnd-5e tag if so)?

Comment: @sdjz I am trying to figure out where to mark the spoilers for this published adventure.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I've attempted an initial pass at adding spoiler tags to the relevant parts; feel free to review them and edit it if you feel my spoiler tags don't make sense.

Comment: @V2Blast Looks good to me, I had a notion to edit the title but decided that I needed to wait and think.  So long as spoilers are addressed, I think we can feel confident in no complaints in re spoilers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## You've read the map and notes right.

As you say...

> The tunnel that branches towards B3 does not have a walkway. If you want to go that way, the sewage is 3' deep.

Your players may choose to just go for it. It's gross, but...

> Not actually harmful unless they are in the sewage for a full minute.

Of course, your players may get creative and try to work out other ways to navigate the passage. Just to give a few examples based on stuff my players have pulled in the past... (Note: these will have to be adjudicated by you as to whether or not they will be feasible, since the campaign doesn't cover them)

> "How rough are the walls? Can I climb horizontally across the wall to avoid going into the sewage?"
>  "I want to cobble together some basic stilts to walk through the sewage without going in."
>  "I bet the city workers have a way to get around here...like a very-narrow-raft. Let's see if we can borrow one!"

And so on.

So, yes...you have a correct understanding of how the space is laid out. So leave it up to your players to figure out how to traverse the space.

Comment: Awesome answer!  I'm definitely new here and that was really helpful!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Your last sentence is the only answer I was going to give, and I chose not to answer as we usually prefer more meat.  Another +1 for the usual quality product  from  guildsbounty productions, LTD, LLC, INC, LMOP.

Comment: I agree that the last answer is the key - the DM’s role is to provide challenges, its the player’s role to find solutions (if they can)